# Conflicting Types error for typedef (timer_t)

Tags: c, gcc, typedef

I am currently compiling my code using the ARM GCC compiler. My code, which has an RTOS, has a *types.h* file which typedefs clock_t to unsigned long. Since the ARM GCC compiler also has a typedef for `clock_t`, I am getting a conflicting types issue for the same.

I have tried including the *.h* file from GCC and undefining the same as suggested in some of the forums but it is not working either. I don't see the *time.h* file from GCC being included in any of my project source files either.

Comment: You can't undefine a type, only macros.

Comment: What if you (ab)use the preprocessor with a `#define` before including `types.h`?

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround would be

```
typedef unsigned long int custom_clock_t;
#define clock_t custom_clock_t
```

this way the compiler will replace every occurrence of `clock_t` before compiling the file with `custom_clock_t` and the conflict will disappear while keeping the familiar `clock_t` syntax intact.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to workaround it by doing some preprocessor magic:

```
#include <sys/types.h> // Or whatever is the other header that defines clock_t
#define clock_t types_clock_t
#include <types.h>
#undef clock_t

clock_t my_variable;
types_clock_t my_other_variable;
```

Take into account that this solution is delicate, and will cause further issues on some circumstances, such as some other code you don't have control over using `<types.h>`'s `clock_t`, or something of the like.